# jquery loop to create elements with retained values

Tags: jquery, loops

I recently asked a question about creating elements with jquery. Specifically I needed input boxes created/deleted depending on the value of a particular select box. This was answered quickly with a very nice solution as follows:

```
$('select').change(function() {
     var num = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
     var container = $('<div />');
     for(var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
         container.append('<input id="id'+i+'" name="name'+i+'" />');
     }
     $('somewhere').html(container);
});
```

This works very well. Is there a way to have the values remaining in the text boxes when the selection is changed? For example, lets say the select element value is set to '2' so that there are 2 input boxes showing. If there is input already entered in these boxes and the user changes the select element value to '3' is there a way to get the first 2 input boxes to retain their value?

Thanks for the help in advance

Andy

Comment: There is also the case where a lower number is selected and I assume the input boxes need to be truncated (from the highest numbered ID back). What have you tried so far?

Comment: Heads up. Putting container.append inside the for loop is very bad for performance. Rather concatenate all the markup inside the loop (using += or array.push) and use that markup in one .append operation after the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line **should** work, nice and simple:

```
var value = ($("#id"+i).val() || '');
container.append('<input id="id'+i+'" name="name'+i+'" value="'+value+'" />');
```

Edited, thanks patrick.

Comment: This would insert `undefined` if there's no existing `input`. (Also "id" is in the wrong place. Should be "#id".) You could test for `undefined` first, like `var value = ($("#id"+i).val() || '');`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select').change(function() {
     var num = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
     var container = $('<div />');
     for(var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {

         // append existing input if available
         if($("#id"+i).length){
            container.append($("#id"+i));
         }
         else {
             container.append('<input id="id'+i+'" name="name'+i+'" />');
         }
     }
     $('somewhere').html(container);
});
```

Comment: This line `if($("#id"+i)) {...` will always return true. You would need `if($("#id"+i).length){` instead.